# How to know the version of RPM during installation

Tags: unix, yum, rpm, rpmbuild

I have created a script for deployment using YUM and RPM. During the `pre` script, is it possible to know whats the version of the rpm I am deploying.

I want to create a backup file with the version of the RPM (in its name) so that i can trace back the version of the RPM file.

I am ok if it is some base unix or RPM or YUM command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean the version of the RPM file you're installing.  In that case it's in the `%version` macro.  However, you probably want the `Release` tag, too.  So you probably want to do something like:

```
echo "{%version}-{%release}" > %{_datadir}/%{name}/rpmver
```

If you want the version of RPM itself:

```
rpm --version > %{_datadir}/%{name}/rpmver
```

Comment: What does %{_datadir}/%{name}/rpmver give ?

Comment: @explorer:  `/usr/share/package-name/rpmver`  The Fedora Project has [an excellent overview of the various RPM macros and how to create/modify spec files in general](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package).